# Is my AES/CTR/RIPEMD encryption correctly implemented?

Tags: cryptography, php, code-review

Below is my encryption implementation in PHP. It's based on mcrypt, and uses AES-128 in CTR mode along with a RIPEMD-128 HMAC for integrity checking.

For brevity, I've inlined the functions for calculating HMAC, verifying HMACs, directly int encrypt/decrypt functions. On the other hand, I've added more comments below than the original code has, to ensure that what happens can be properly understood by people unfamiliar with PHP<sup>1</sup>.

```
function encrypt($data, $key, $hmac_key) {
  // Get the appropriate IV size for AES-128/CTR
  $ivSize = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, 'ctr');

  // Create a random IV.
  $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($ivSize, MCRYPT_RAND);

  // Encrypt with AES-128/CTR with the provided key.
  $encrypted = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $data, 'ctr', $iv);

  // Base HMAC on the contatenated IV, the encrypted data and the cipher identifier.
  $hmac_data = $iv . $encrypted . MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128;

  // Calculate HMAC using ripemd128 and the supplied HMAC key.
  $hmac = hash_hmac('ripemd128', $hmac_data, $hmac_key);

  // Concatenate together the IV, encrypted data, and hmac, and base 64 encode them.
  return base64_encode($iv . $encrypted . $hmac);
}

function decrypt($encrypted, $key, $hmac_key) {
  // Decode from base 64.
  $encrypted = base64_decode($encrypted);

  // Get the appropriate IV size for AES-128/CTR
  $ivSize = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, 'ctr');

  // Grab the IV and HMAC from the data.
  $iv = substr($encrypted, 0, $ivSize);
  $hmac = substr($encrypted, -32);

  // Cut out the remaining data, which is the cipher text.
  $encrypted = substr($encrypted, $ivSize, -32);

  // Base HMAC on the contatenated IV, the encrypted data and the cipher identifier.
  $hmac_data = $iv . $encrypted . MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128;

  // Calculate verification HMAC using ripemd128 and the supplied HMAC key.
  $verification_hmac = hash_hmac('ripemd128', $hmac_data, $hmac_key);

  $verification = true;
  // Refuse to proceed if the two HMACs are of different length.
  if (strlen($hmac) !== strlen($verification_hmac)) {
    return NULL;
  }

  // Always iterate over the entire length of the HMACs to avoid timing information.
  for($i = 0; $i < strlen($verification_hmac); $i++) {
    // Check for strict equality for each character.
    if($verification_hmac[$i] !== $verification_hmac[$i]) {
      $verification = false;
    }
  }

  // Refuse to proceed if the two HMACs don't match exactly.
  if (!$verification) {
    return NULL;
  }

  $decrypted = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $encrypted, 'ctr', $iv);

  return $decrypted;
}
```

<sup>1</sup>: I'm thinking primarily of the concatenation operator, dot (.), which may not be entirely obvious.

Comment: A few other things (aside the RIPEMD128 which was already mentioned by Polynomial) caught my eye. You should be using MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM as the randomness source, as it is safe for cryptographic use (here it is especially important to have definitely a fresh nonce for every encryption), whereas MCRYPT_RAND is not. Also, the HMAC verification leaks timing information (as === comparison uses branches). As a side note, some other things to consider when implementing crypto (in PHP): http://timoh6.github.io/2014/06/16/PHP-data-encryption-cheatsheet.html

Comment: @timoh Very good link, thank you. I'll fix the randomness source. I don't know how to avoid the timing problem though. Some googling seems to suggest that I need to be using bitwise ops, but I don't understand it enough. Could you shed any more light on the topic?

Comment: About constant-time string comparison, check http://rdist.root.org/2009/05/28/timing-attack-in-google-keyczar-library/ and for a specific PHP implementation you can use for example https://github.com/timoh6/TCrypto/blob/master/library/TCrypto/Crypto.php#L459 (if you choose to use constant-time comparison instead of "double HMACing").

Answer (score 2):

Looks fine to me, except your use of RIPEMD128, about which Wikipedia has this to say:

> The 128-bit version was intended only as a drop-in replacement for the original RIPEMD, which was also 128-bit, and which had been found to have questionable security.

I suggest you choose a better hash for your authenticity, e.g. SHA256 or at least RIPEMD160.